# Apple IAP Con-consumable purchase assignable to application account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have application that allows user to create more content to be used by them. Apple IAP states that non-consumable purchase can be restored by mandatory `Restore Purchases` button. Current flow of purchase process in our app looks like this:

1. User purchases non-consumable content via IAP
2. Receipt code is send to backend application
3. If receipt gets validated against Apple API - we add content to his account in our app.

Problem here is - user can purchase some content, and then log into all his friends accounts and restore his purchases there.

I was thinking about two solutions to this problem:

1. Making non-consumable content consumable - and by consuming I mean consuming it by our API. I am not sure if apple will allow us to do this
2. Keep track of receipts in backend and if user will want to restore receipt previously assigned to another account - ignore it.

Is any of my propositions valid, or there is another way to prevent such exploitation I mentioned?

Comment: I would go with option 2

Answer (score 1):

You can't set Consumable type for your in-app purchases unless it is related to internal currency or something like that. 
If your in-app purchase is designed to unlock some content, it must be non-consumable and restorable.

So, I wouldn't recommend option 1. As for option 2, you may try to do it this way:

```
1. Keep the list of receipts for all purchased products assigned to
every account in your system
2. When Restore purchases is pressed, get the list of purchased products via StoreKit and send it to your server. 
3. If they match, unlock the content, 
4. If they don't match, show an error, that some of requested content was assigned to another account.
```